# GCC 4.8.1 to GCC 4.6.3

Tags: gcc

i am using ubuntu 12.04. Initially ubuntu 12.04 have gcc 4.6.3 with it. I upgraded it to 4.8.1. But now one of my application that was working fine with 4.6.3 are not working with 4.8.1. I want to downgrade it to 4.6.3.

Comment: How did you upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

After downloading gcc-4.6.3 follow this steps:

```
sudo su -
cd /usr/bin
ls -l gcc*
```

You have to see like this at the end `gcc -> 4.8` with light blue colered.

```
rm gcc
ln -s gcc-4.6 gcc
```

And finally to check if gcc linked to gcc-4.6 enter follow command:

```
ls -l gcc*
```

You have to see like this at the end `gcc -> 4.6` with light blue colered.

Comment: but how to download gcc 4.6.3???

Comment: In Software Center find `gcc-4.6` ant select Install button or use terminal `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6`

Comment: but this installs 4.6.4 and i need specifically 4.6.3??

Comment: You must googling! Download from here http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.6.3/